# Converting from bytes into gigabytes

Tags: powershell

I am using following script to get disk space audit in our enterprise environment.

Everything works fine except that I don't know how to get those values presented in GB/MB.

Any idea?

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path D:\DISKSPACE_audit\Servers.txt 
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computers | Where-Object {
  $_.DriveType -eq 3
} | Select-Object SystemName,DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size
```

Answer (score 6):

Divide the value by `1GB` (or `1MB`):

```
$Computers = Get-Content "D:\DISKSPACE_audit\Servers.txt"
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $Computers -Filter 'DriveType = 3' |
    Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID,
        @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
        @{n='Size';e={[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}
```