# Power shell convert bytes to gb

Tags: powershell

Below power shell code will find all directories below the current directory,
and determine their size. How to change below code, in order to get result in gb?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } |
    Select-Object FullName,
        @{ Name="Size";
        Expression={ ($_ | Get-ChildItem | 
            Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum + 0 } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Converting from bytes into gigabytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748325/powershell-converting-from-bytes-into-gigabytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, simply divide `Sum` by `1GB` :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } |
    Select-Object FullName, @{
        Name = "Size"
        Expression = { ($_ | Get-ChildItem | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum / 1GB } }
```

If you want to limit the number of decimals (2 in this example), you can use:

```
"{0:N2}" -f 12.33333333
```

which would output

```
12.33
```